# Spark Hivecontext not executing the query when run from Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hivecontext, spark-hive

I have a Scala program  wherein I create a hivecontext and run a hive query from it. The hive query is a multi-table insert query. I am facing issues where the query runs successfully but I cannot see the out being generated. Interesting thing is that if in the multi-table inert query I insert into one table the query is running successfully i.e I can see the out data.
For example:

```
val hiveContext = = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)
```

Query that is not generating data:

```
hiveContext.sql("FROM source_table INSERT INTO destiantion_table_1 PARTITION (...)
INSERT INTO destination_table_2 PARTITION (...)
INSERT INTO destination_table_3 PARTITION (...)")
```

Query that is working fine:

```
hiveContext.sql("FROM source_table INSERT INTO destiantion_table_1 PARTITION (...)
```

I looked into the executor logs there was no error reported for the  query that did not execute.

I am running Spark 1.5 on YARN

Let me know if any additional information is required on the above .

Comment: So you assume that the Spark SQL compiler supports each and every fancy feature of the Hive SQL compiler (e.g. the multi-table insert using that bizarre "FROM - INSERT" syntax). That makes you an optimist.

Comment: ok..please guide me on how i can determine which feature of hive is supported and which is not? thanks

Comment: _"how i can determine ..."_ -- that's exactly what you are doing: trying something, checking whether it works as expected or not, trying sthg else. And start again with the next Spark release.